# SFDX push with private accounts error for AccountShare objects

Tags: salesforcedx, apex-managed-sharing

we are trying to use SFDX for continuous integration in one of our projects. We are setting the account sharing model to private, and from code add some manual sharing on accounts. However in an SFDX project we cannot manage to do this, because in source push in a newly created scratch org this gives us back the error message: **Field is not writeable: AccountShare.*** on every field.

To reproduce this you only need to add the object definitions for the Account, Case, Contact and Opportunity like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <sharingModel>Private</sharingModel>
</CustomObject>
```

And a class:

```
public with sharing class TestAccountShare {
   public static void insertAccountShare() {
      AccountShare aShare = new AccountShare();
      aShare.AccountAccessLevel = 'Read';
   }
}
```

In this case when you try to push the source on a new scratch org it fails. If you only push the object definitions first and in a second push the TestAccountShare class it is successful. It is a workaround during development but you still cannot create a package version with this.

Has anyone any ideas to resolve this?